# How to use microk8s kubectl after host reboot (Hyper-V)

Tags: microk8s

I have a fully functional MicroK8s running in my Hyper-V. After my host rebooted, I can't use `microk8s kubectl` anymore. I always get the following error:

```bash
microk8s kubectl get node -o wide
```

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp `172.31.119.125:16443`: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

As I know, the master node IP been changed. If I update the KUBECONFIG locally, I can connect to cluster without problem.

```
microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
```

But if I want to use `microk8s kubectl get node -o wide` to get node status, I always can't get it working. I'm still unable to connect to the server.

I tried to clear all possible cache by removing all `.kube/cache` folders. But still not working.

```
sudo rm -rf /.kube/cache /root/.kube/cache /home/ubuntu/.kube/cache /var/snap/microk8s/3582/.kube/cache
```

I stopped and started MicroK8s again. I'm still unable to connect to the server.

```
microk8s stop
microk8s start
```

After MicroK8s restarted, I also tried to find out all files that contains `172.31.119.125` ip address.

```bash
grep '172.31.119.125' -r /
```

Nothing useful found. Only `/var` contains some logs with `172.31.119.125`. That's so weird. Is there anything I can try? How to connect to MicroK8s using `microk8s kubectl`?

Answer (score 2):

After 1 hours deep dive, I finally realized there is a `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\MicroK8s\config` file used by `MicroK8s` which the [doc](https://microk8s.io/docs/working-with-kubectl#heading--kubectl-windows) never said.

All you need to do is the update the `config` file by the following ways:

**PowerShell**

```
microk8s config > $env:LOCALAPPDATA\MicroK8s\config
```

**Command Prompt**

```
microk8s config > %LOCALAPPDATA%\MicroK8s\config
```